# maps  of oo-stacks inducing monomorphisms on all homotopy sheaves

Tags: simplicial-stuff, topos-theory

What is known about factoring morphisms of simplicial (pre)sheaves/$\infty$-sheaves through maps that induce monomorphisms on all homotopy sheaves? Is there any useful theory for that?